# matlab, frequency calculation and code review

Tags: matlab, statistics, frequency, review

i've got a logical/statistical problem:

i have to find out if the fire rate according to four different stimuli given to a neuron are significantly different. 
I calculated the frequencies via psth/binning method in matlab and i am not sure if it was the right way. Following i did an anova and a tukey-test via jmp. At first sight it looks good but as mentioned before i don't think the calculation was correct.

Maybe its not the right forum for my problem but perhaps some g can find my mistake or has a better solution. Thanks:D

bins is the number of bins calculated by total duration (800ms) divided by binwidth(10ms). 
At the end this function should give me a histogram plotted with freq over time (ms) and the frequencies (here a 1x80 vector with the average freq per bin).
Done for four different stimuli i got 4 vectors, put in jmd and done the tukey.

```
function [freq] = BinFireRate(data, dur, times_snippet, binwidth)
%function that plots the firing rate of a given dataset via binning method in [hz]
%in: dataset (n x m-matrix), dur as duarion observed from trial
%time_snippet (1,n-vector) for convert data into time values [ms]
%binwidth
%out: histogram of firing rate (freq) over time and frequency [hz]
%[1x80-vector] itself

bins = dur / binwidth;

spiketimes_stim = data .* times_snippet;
spiketimes_stim = spiketimes_stim(spiketimes_stim ~= 0);

[spikes_per_bin, bincenters] = hist(spiketimes_stim, bins);
freq = ((spikes_per_bin / binwidth) / length(data(:, 1))) * 1000;
bar(bincenters, freq);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this is not a programming problem (it's in your method rather, at least that's what you suspect) this does not belong on Stack Overflow. I can't point you anywhere else at this time, as your information on your method is, at least to me, to limited to tell you where it went wrong. Please take the [tour] and read [the list of topics one can ask about here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please inform what kind of theory you are using.  This seems to me like a
 problem for [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but most of what you wrote makes no sense to me.